# SignatureDoesNotMatch when accessing the S3 pre-signed url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I created a Lambda function to generate pre-signed URL for mobile app users to access pdf document on S3 (not public).

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    resp = s3.list_objects(
        Bucket='xxxxxxxxx',
        EncodingType='url',
        MaxKeys=1,
        Prefix='2',
        RequestPayer='requester'
    )
    key = resp['Contents'][0]['Key']
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': 'xxxxxxxxx',
            'Key': key,
            'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'AES256',
            'ResponseContentType': 'application/pdf'
            },
        ExpiresIn=3600,
        HttpMethod='GET'
        )
```

then I get this on the browser.

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
```

To my understanding it is accessible by HTTP request.

With Curl

```
curl -X GET https://pre-signedurlhere --output test.pdf
```

then

> The file “test.pdf” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise.

Comment: It looks you haven't included the code that actually makes the request and results in the error. Can you share the code that generates the signature and makes the request?

Comment: @bwest Directry accessing the URL using Chrome browser causes "SignatureDoesNotMatch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if using list_objects_v2 had any effect but I finally managed to get the access to file from the pre-signed url with the following code. Did not change any settings on AWS.

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    resp = s3.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket='Bucket-name-here',
        MaxKeys=1,
        Prefix='2',
        RequestPayer='requester'
    )
    key = resp['Contents'][0]['Key']
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': '',
            'Key': key,
            'ResponseContentType': 'application/pdf'
            },
        ExpiresIn=3600,
        HttpMethod='GET'
        )
```